# how to open window in west region of border layout?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a border layout implemented with West and Center regions. I've buttons in West region and ideally windows should open in center region. Can someone guide, how it shall be done? Do I need to specify 'renderTo' property somehow to open window in Center Region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the window's [showBy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-showBy) function, you can specify a component or element that the window will appear by. If you call `window.showBy(center)` with `center` being the component in the layout with the config `region: center`, you should see what you're looking for.

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tbg) to illustrate one way of getting the center component from within the button handler

Comment: Jaimee! showby  did not work for me. I tried to add East Region too and specifically mentioned about east region but it keeps showing up in center region.

Comment: @Sam I updated the fiddle with an eastern region. What region are you wanting the window to show in? Your question is titled 'west', the question itself says 'center' and now you're talking about an eastern region. In the fiddle, you can replace the word "center" in `button.up('container[reference="main-container"]').down('[region="center"]')` with "east" or "west" if you prefer.